# WebHostBuilder. How to set url address using CommandLine in .NET-Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use below code to add CommandLine in my .Net-Core 1.2 environment, I can use the command line like `dotnet run --urls "http://a.cn.com:5000" --environment "Production"`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();

     var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .Build();

     host.Run();
}
```

And After migrate to .net core 2.0 it becomes like that

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
                {
                    logging.AddSerilog();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
 }
```

I use the same command line ,it fails.
How to add the Command in .net core 2.0 ?

**Supply: 2017.08.17**
launchsetting.json below :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5005/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Robert.Project.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5006"
    }
  }
}
```

What I expect the listening is
`Now listening on http://a.cn.com:5000`
What I get is that:

> [image]

**And we should not add any other code in `Program.cs` file, cause CreateDefaultBuilder is contain addCommandLine. for more detail, you can see [WebHost.cs#L177](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L177)**

**Supply 2017 0817 17:44 UTC+8**

> [::] is the IPv6 equivalent of IPv4 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I use the command `dotnet run --urls "http://a.cn.com:5000"` it  Now listening on: `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: so is a.cn.com an alias for localhost on your development machine, or the production server? or do you think it ignores the --urls argument and defaults to localhost? it could well be the first because it got the port right...

Comment: a.cn.com is an alias for localhost on my development machine.

Comment: The error show in the console is `The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.`

Comment: is there a launchsettings.json file? I think that's what it will be looking for by default

Comment: @robert have you solved your problem?

Comment: @Set When I use dotnet run  it's still the result that I write in the supply

Comment: @robert see my updated answer, it explains (with a link to the same issue desc) why you need to call `.UseConfiguration` directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UseConfiguration` directly to set url address populated by args:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

---

> And we should not add any other code in Program.cs file, cause CreateDefaultBuilder is contain addCommandLine. for more detail, you can see WebHost.cs#L177

This is not exactly true, as linked `CreateDefaultBuilder` implementation uses `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method, not `UseConfiguration`. And there is a difference (from related [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1148)):

> The `ConfigureAppConfiguration` was intended to configure the `IConfiguration` in the application services whereas `UseConfiguration` is intended to configure the settings of the `WebHostBuilder`. Since the url address is a setting on the `WebHostBuilder` only `UseConfiguration` will work here.
>
> Note that the WebHostBuilder's configuration is added to the application's configuration but the converse is not true; configuring the application's configuration does not affect the WebHostBuilder's configuration.

Comment: I have tried this but command line arguments are getting overridden by launchsettings.json which didn't use to happen