# "dotnet run" in Docker Container results in inaccessible url

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a development environment with ASP.Net Core and Docker. The image builds correctly, and the container runs without issue. However, even though i have specified the port to be 5000 for both the host and the container, dotnet still launches the server at an url which neither contains the specified port, nor is it accessible. I was expecting the listener to be at: `http://localhost:5000`

`docker-compose up` results in:

```
Recreating netcore_ms1_1 ...
Recreating netcore_ms1_1 ... done
Attaching to netcore_ms1_1
ms1_1  | Hosting environment: Production
ms1_1  | Content root path: /app
ms1_1  | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
ms1_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My application is just a sample `dotnet new web` app template. Here are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0-jessie
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  ms1:
    build: ./ms1
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./ms1:/app:Z
```

Can someone point out to me what i am missing?

**Additional question**

How would i proceed to run the Dotnet Watcher Tools in a Docker container, more specifically to run `dotnet watch run` and watch for file changes in the mounted volume ./ms1?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it's listening on 80 but you're trying to access 5000. Easiest solution is probably just having 5000 redirect to 80 in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: I tried changing the port in docker-compose.yml, but the result is the same.

Comment: Is port changed If you do `dotnet run  --server.urls "http://0.0.0.0:5000"` from console? `--server.urls` works only if you explicitly enable reading configs from args (while setup WebHost). Have you added `.AddCommandLine(args)`? Look into [WebHostBuilder. How to set url address using CommandLine in .NET-Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710570/webhostbuilder-how-to-set-url-address-using-commandline-in-net-core-2-0/45712524#45712524) if need sample.

Comment: Consider asking your dotnet-watch question separately. It is better to have one question per post so answers can stay on point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `microsoft/aspnetcore-build` or `microsoft/aspnetcore`, the image is pre-configured to expose port 80. Launch your container like this instead:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0-jessie
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

On command-line,

```
docker run -p 5000:80
```

Or in docker-compose.yml,

```
ports: 
  - "5000:80"
```

This default comes from the definition of the `microsoft/aspnetcore` images, which set the `ASPNETCORE_URL` environment variable to `http://+:80`.

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
```

See https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/blob/v2.0.0/2.0/jessie/runtime/Dockerfile#L4