# Connecting to Docker Container .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core

So i am trying to dockerize  a .NET Core Project. I was able to create the image and run the container , however I'm not able to connect to the container even though i exposed the port.
I used this command to run the container:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp aspnetapp
```

and when i run and check the logs the following is present:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://+:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

This is my Program.cs

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

and this is my DockerFile:

```
   FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1.2 AS build-env
    WORKDIR /app

   # Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
    COPY ./*.sln ./ 
    RUN dotnet restore nde-configuration-editor.sln

   # Copy everything else and build
    COPY . ./
    RUN dotnet restore ./nde-configuration-editor
    RUN dotnet restore ./AspNetCore.Identity.InMemory

    RUN dotnet publish nde-configuration-editor.sln -c Release -o out

    # Build runtime image
    FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=build-env /app/nde-configuration-editor/out .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "nde-configuration-editor.dll"]
```

I try connecting from browser using http://localhost:8080 it gives site can't be reached.
What I am missing?How can i connect to the container?Any Help?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get when connecting?

Comment: i try connecting using localhost:8080 , it gives this site couldn't be reached.@yamenk

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail please show your `Program.cs` (especially how you setup host) and `Dockerfile`

Comment: i added it!@Set

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail  in general, everything looks ok and should work if your app is really listening to the 80 port while running in the container... Try to use different ports for both docker and app (like 8081:5000) - maybe you have some firewall/proxy issues. Also, any specific reason why you haven't updates to asp.net core 2.0? You may check/reuse the official  [dotnet-sample](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/tree/master/aspnetapp) for docker.

Answer (score 0):

Add "ASPNETCORE_URLS http://0.0.0.0:80" environmental variable .

Or change here directly ( prior to .net core RC2 ) in project.json of web-app root.

```
"commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:80"
},
```

For .netcore RC2

```
create file hosting.json in web-app root and add 
{
  "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
}
```

And it requires changes in code.

Else easiest way is to run is

```
dotnet run --server.urls "http://0.0.0.0:80"
```

Here its documented 
https://andrewlock.net/configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: Where do you mean here directly?In Which file exactly?

Comment: I added UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:80;http://localhost:80") , it gave me this error while trying to run the container:http://localhost:80 on the IPv4 loopback interface: port already in use

Comment: i tried using only 0.0.0.0:80. The container Runs however //localhost:8080 still gives site can't be reached.

Comment: @sanathmeti note that `--server.urls` doesn't work out of the box, you first need to setup the configuration provider to use args as a source. Actually your link mentioned that (you look into [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710570/webhostbuilder-how-to-set-url-address-using-commandline-in-net-core-2-0/45712524#45712524)). For debugging the `.UseUrls` is easier way to change listening settings.

Comment: I didnt understand.What should i do? I tried first the .UseuRL but it didnt work.The i tried the enviromental variables in the launch.json and nothing changed too.!