# Cannot use `--urls "http:*:8080"` to overwrite the port?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

The following link says the port can be overridden by command-line argument `dotnet run --urls "http://*:8080"`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#overriding-configuration

The following is my `Program` class of my Asp.Net core app. However, it still shows it's listening on http://localhost:5000?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => 
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to affect the `WebHost` settings, you need to call `UseConfiguration` with an implementation of `IConfiguration`. In your example, you are using only `ConfigureAppConfiguration`, which does not apply to the `WebHost`.

Here's an example:

```
var webHostConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

return WebHost.CreateDefaultuBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseConfiguration(webHostConfiguration)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(...) // No changes.
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` will properly work for *urls* override only with ASP.NET Core 2.1 version.

There was an [/MetaPackages/issues/221](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/issues/221) about this and [fix](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/pull/241/files) mainly adds the following logic into `CreateDefaultBuilder` method

```
if (args != null)
{
   builder.UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build());
}
```

so right now you need to directly add this code:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build())
        ...
```

---

And just in case if you are interested why the following doesn't do the fix

```
   .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
   {
      ...
      config.AddCommandLine(args);
   })
```

check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710570/webhostbuilder-how-to-set-url-address-using-commandline-in-net-core-2-0/45712524#45712524)

Answer (score 0):

Docs says ". The command-line argument overrides the urls value from the hosting.json file". You do not have hosting.json file. Add hosting.json using following line of code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace NewTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }             

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();                                    

            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .Configure(app =>
                {
                    //This is required otherwise application will throw the exception.                                      
                })
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

}

Once you add hosting.json, configuration can be overridden by command line.

Comment: Added `.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)` and still not working.

Comment: @ca9163d9, Slightly modified the code. You can find the working example in github repository https://github.com/paragpkulkarni/AspNetCoreTestWithJsonConfig